# Python passing variables from filedialog to mainloop

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to build a GUI in python for a program.

For this program I have a configuration file which I want to be able to open and pass to the program. What I have for now (in short) is this:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

def openfile():
  filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root)
  lst = list(open(filename))

def savefile():
  filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(parent=root)

root = Tk()

methodmenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)
methodmenu.add_command(label="Open",command=openfile)
methodmenu.add_command(label="Save",command=savefile)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Config",menu=methodmenu)

label = Label(root,text="show config here")
label.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor=CENTER)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

So the openfile function reads the config file in a list (which is what I want). Now, how do I pass this to my mainloop? If for example I want to display information read from that file in a `Label` in my `root` window?

I tried defining `openfile()` with `openfile(lst)` and declaring `lst=[""]` before adding the command, but that seems to be wrong (program calls openfile(lst) immediatly on startup, lst is empty in the label).

I'm new to python and GUIs in general, this apparently doesn't work like fortran...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return the contents of the configuration file you read in `openfile`, and pass the contents of the file to a `Label` constructor. Note that since the `Label` constructor takes a single string, that's what you'll have to convert your list to:

```
def openfile():
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root)
    return list(open(filename))

...

config_file_contents = ''.join(openfile())
label = Label(root, text=config_file_contents)
label.place(...)
```

Or if you want to display each element in your configuration list individually, you can loop through each element in your configuration file list and pass each element into it's own separate `Label` object:

```
for config in openfile():
    label = Label(root, text=config)
    label.place(...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. With your first solution it works, but it automatically calls the openfile() function immediatly on startup..?

Comment: Yes, @Fl.pf., it does. When you run your code, `openfile` is immediately be called. Is this not what you want? Perhaps you want to save the return value of `openfile` and use it later. If so, simply assign it to a variable.

Comment: yes I want the `openfile` to only execute if I click on the `Open` button in the cascade

Comment: I also can't call `Open` again, nothing happens when I click the Button